# Working with Radio Buttons and GUI's

Tags: user-interface, radio-button, autohotkey

I've been learning to use GUI's with Autohotkey, and I'm creating a small script so when I press the insert button it allows me to quick search Google. I can't figure out how to use Radio Buttons, so say for example, I can choose to search Google or Bing. I don't know any of the code for "If Google is selected, search the query on Google".

```
^Insert::
MsgBox,4,, Would you like to reload?, 3

IfMsgBox, no
Return
IfMsgBox, Timeout
Return
Reload

Insert::
Gui, Add, Text,, Search Google:
Gui, Add, Edit, vSearchQuery ym  ; 
Gui, Add, Button, default, Search  
Gui, Show,, Quick Search
return


GuiClose:
ButtonSearch:
Gui, Submit  
Run, http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q=%searchQuery% 
Reload
```

Comment: Please read this: http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/IfExpression.htm

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple example:

```
Gui Add, Radio, vEngine, Google
Gui Add, Radio,, Bing
Gui Add, Button, h25 w126 Default,OK
Gui Show
Return

ButtonOK:
Gui Submit
if Engine = 1
    msgbox % "You chose Google!"    
else if Engine = 2
    msgbox % "You chose Bing!"
ExitApp
```